# Calling user defined functions inside a script in R.Net

Tags: c#, r, r.net

I'm having trouble calling my own R functions using R.Net; I have several user defined functions inside some R scripts myScript.R, ..., and I want to call this functions using R.net

this is what I've got so far

one myScript.R file contains several functions like this

```
userDefinedFunctionOne <- function(parameter1, parameter2)
{
.
.
.
}

userDefinedFunctionTwo <- function(parameter1, parameter2, ...)
.
.
.
```

and with R.Net, in the constructor of my class I create an instance of the REngine class

```
private REngine engine;

public MyClass()
{
     this.engine = REngine.GetInstance();
}
```

then I source the myScript.R file

```
this.engine.Evaluate(@"source('C:/RScripts/myScript.R')");
```

but when I call my functions like this

```
var dataframe = this.engine.Evaluate(string.Format("dataframe <- userDefinedFunctionOne(parameter1 = {0}, parameter2 = {1})",
                                                        value1,
                                                        value2)).AsDataFrame();
```

I'm getting this error

> Error: could not find function "userDefinedFunctionOne"

I've found seen some examples when the user functions is defined like this

```
Function data = engine.Evaluate(@"data <- function(a,b){ 
    c = a %*% b;
    return(c);
    }").AsFunction();
```

but I want to avoid that, because as I wrote, I have several functions inside my R script files

is there a way to do this without rewriting my R functions as strings???

I would apreciate any help, 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is just fine and should work (good post by the way, thank you). I do not understand why `userDefinedFunctionOne` is not found, since it should have been loaded in the global R environment.

I've added a bit of code in one of the sample applications I use:
[SourceRCode](https://github.com/jmp75/rdotnet-onboarding/tree/master/SourceRCode)

The code derived from your post ran just fine, I could see the expected data frame from visual studio in debug mode. Can you give it a try and report if you have the issue or not with this sample application?

The sample application uses the latest NuGet package (1.6.5 as of writing), but 
it looks like you are using a recent version of R.NET given the methods, and I to not expect version to the be cause of the issue.

Comment: the problem was that I wasn't calling `REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();` before getting the Rengine instance `this.engine = REngine.GetInstance();` I saw that in the example, added that line and it's working now, Thank You